# cannot start nodejs web api hosted in Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, restify

Learning `nodejs` and started to created my own restful API using restify.

I have created a very simple `server.js` file which contains basically a hello world type example starting up like:

```
server.post('/api/messages', servicemanager.verifyFramework(), servicemanager.listen());

server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    'directory': '.',
    'default': 'index.html'
}));

server.listen(process.env.port || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});
```

which works fine locally. I cant hit http://localhost:3978 and I can test my API calls just fine calling http://localhost:3978/api/messages.

I have deployed my code into bitbucket and now I want to host these APIs in Azure using `App Services`.

My project structure is like so:

```
/topfolder
  -/myproject
     -/node_modules
       -/node_modules...
     server.js
     package.json
     index.html
```

When I setup the new app service in Azure, I can see that the deployment receives the code from BB, but the service never responds to my requests.

I have setup the home path of the app to live in: `/site/wwwroot/topfolder/myproject` and I can see the `index.html` when I navigate to http://myproject.azurewebsites.net so thats good.

I actually get a 404 error: 
`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

There are heaps of examples of how to setup continuous deployment using bitbucket and for the most part, they all seem to work, but my `server.js` file doesnt seem to be the getting called or starting up.

How can I debug whats going on here?

Is the `packages.json` file used in this scenario by Azure?

Thanks.

Comment: If you FTP into your azure website there is a log somewhere. There aren't a lot of directories to poke around in but in one of the files above your project in the directory structure I'm pretty positive there is a log file that should contain any console output logged from your app.

Comment: What url are you using, to hit your hosted api?

Comment: @Chev thanks, thats the debug console, i have looked around but nothing jumps out at me. Any clues?

Comment: @DavidMakogon im hitting: http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/messages as a http post request. Locally, I hit http://localhost:3978/api/messages which works (when I make sure that node is running of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the root directory path of the application hosted on Azure App Services, is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. And about the nodejs application, the Azure fabric will find the entrance script in root directory like `server.js`. And the requests are handled via `web.config` in root directory. If there is missing `server.js` or `web,config` file, you will occur 404 error.

You can try to modify or your application's structure, like to:

```
-/node_modules
  -/node_modules...
server.js
package.json
index.html
```

Then, you deploy your application to Azure via GIT or from BB, the Azure deployment task will run command `npm install` and generate the `web.config` wile in the root directory.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Looks like you just have to have this structure then, for now that worked for me even though it was a massive pain. Thanks Gary.